# Access Azure Application Settings using IConfiguration

Tags: c#, azure

I have a setting in my Application settings on my Azure Web App set up like so:

[image: Azure App Settings]

I'm trying to access it in the code like so: `configuration["AppSettings:LASTFM_API_KEY"]`

This works when I have the secret set up in my secrets.json file like so:

[image: secrets.json]

But not when I publish my app to Azure. I first tried it in Azure as `LASTFM_API_KEY` and then tried adding `AppSettings__`, neither worked.

How can I access this secret when I publish my app? Is it possible to access it using configuration in the same way both locally and when published to Azure?

Comment: Have you added the Environment Variable configuration provider?

Comment: I haven't, is there a specific way I should configure that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#non-prefixed-environment-variables

Comment: That makes some sense, but if I'm reading that correctly, mine should work currently because I'm titling it AppSettings__LASTFM_API_KEY and accessing it as AppSettings:LASTFM_API_KEY should work

Comment: Ahh I see, I had to add my `AddEnvironmentVariables` last so that it wasn't overwritten by the placeholder in my `appsettings.json` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the `AddEnvironmentVariables()` call, and also this needs to be called *after* any calls that might overwrite the value with a similar value in another file (like appsettings.json). I put it last like so:

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```